# Haystack incompatible with Django 1.10?

Tags: django-haystack

while installing django-haystack using PIP with django version==1.10`

```
Collecting django-haystack


Using cached django_haystack-2.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting Django<1.10 (from django-haystack)
  Using cached Django-1.9.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: Django, django-haystack
  Found existing installation: Django 1.10
    Uninstalling Django-1.10:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/django-admin'
```

Why Uninstalling django 1.10 and even why it can't 
Using Ubuntu 16.04

Please Notify me if there is a familiar issue like that or even a question here Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing it with `sudo` ? You usually need to use `sudo` to install some dependencies

Comment: Yes and it uninstalled django 1,10 and installed 1.9.9

Comment: ' Found existing installation: Django 1.10
    Uninstalling Django-1.10:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-1.10
Successfully installed Django-1.9.9 django-haystack-2.5.0
'

Comment: are using installing to a virtualenv?